# Proof that the set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $$M=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 2x^2+xy+y^2+z^2=1\right\}$$ is a bounded set. Without the $xy$ it would be clear but how to get rid of it?

The exercise is to show that a give continuous function has a maximum and a minimun on that set. So I want to show that it's compact, therefore, as we are $\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ it is sufficient to show that it is bounded and closed.

Closed is easy: Let $f(x,y,z)= 2x^2+xy+y^2+z^2$ then $f^{-1}(\{1\})=M$ and $\{1\}$ is closed. As $f$ is continuous, $M$ is closed.

I'm stuck, how to show boundedness?

Thanks!

Comment: Complete the square

Comment: Note: use \{ and \} to display { and } in math mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Letting $X=(x,y,z)$ and $Q=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1/2 & 0\\
1/2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ your set becomes $M=\{X\in \mathbb{R}^3:X^T QX=1\}$

Comment: So as Q is positive definite, all its eigenvalues are positiv and therefore $\lambda_1 ||x||_2 \leq X^TQX \leq \lambda_2 ||x||_2$ where $\lambda_1$ is the smallest and $\lambda_2$ is the greatest eigenvalue. This is the answer is was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly @user254331.

Answer (score 1):

The set of points for which a homogeneous quadratic equation equals one is closed iff the eigenvalues of the corresponding symmetric matrix are positive.

This boils down to checking if a discriminant is negative or not, as pointed by Rory Daulton. Anyway, if we do not want to use the full power of the spectral theorem, we may just notice that by assuming:

$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 3 $$
we have:
$$ 2x^2+xy+y^2+z^2 = \frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2+z^2+\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2) \geq \frac{3}{2} $$
so no point outside the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2< 3$ may belong to $M$.

That trivially implies that $M$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

If we look only at the terms in $x$ and $y$ we have $2x^2+xy+y^2$ which is a quadratic form in $x$ and $y$. Rather famously was can use the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Cartesian_coordinates) $B^2-4AC$ in $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+F=0$  to see that it represents an ellipse.

So, change the coordinates in $x$ and $y$ to rotate that ellipse and get your equation into the

$$\frac{(x')^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y')^2}{b^2}+z^2=C$$

for some positive constant $C$. This is clearly bounded, being an ellipsoid.

Do you remember how to rotate a conic section in the plane?

---

Here is the end result: your equation becomes

$$2\left(x+\frac y4\right)^2+\frac{7y^2}8+z^2=1$$

From that you can get bounds on $y$ and $z$, then use the bounds on $y$ to get bounds on $x$. Another equivalent equation is

$$\frac{7x^2}4+\left(\frac x2+y\right)^2+z^2=1$$

---

I thought of these first as rotations in the $xy$-plane, but I now see that an easier way is simply to complete the square. To get my first equivalent equation complete $2x^2+xy$ and to get the second complete $xy+y^2$. Now is it clear?

Comment: Honestly I have little idea what you are doing. I know that for a symmetric Matrix A a quadratic form is $<x,Ax>$. So there should be $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ representing $2x^2+xy+y^2$ by $<(x,y),A(x,y)>$
But how does that help?

Comment: I was using high-school analytic geometry to rotate the axes to get the equation of an ellipse into standard form. I wasn't really using the full theory of quadratic forms. My edits show that completing the square gives an equivalent answer in less time.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$2x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2  = \left(x+\frac12 y\right)^2 + x^2 + \frac34 y^2 + z^2. $$
As this is a sum of nonnegative numbers, it follows that
\begin{align}
\left|x+\frac12 y\right| &\leqslant 1 \tag 1\\
|x| &\leqslant 1\tag 2\\
\left|\frac{\sqrt3}2 y\right| &\leqslant 1\tag 3\\
|z| &\leqslant 1.\tag 4
\end{align}
From $(3)$, we have $|y|\leqslant\frac{2\sqrt3}3<2,$ so
$$ M\subset\{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb R^3 \mid \max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}<2\},$$
and hence $M$ is bounded.

Comment: This is a nice answer too, as it is very fast and easy!